# How does "each" function work in Ruby (and therefor Rails)?

Tags: ruby, string

In the book I'm reading to learn Rails (RailsSpace) , the author creates two functions (below) to turn all caps city names like LOS ANGELES into Los Angeles.  There's something I don't get about the first function, below, however.

Namely, where does "word" come from? I understand that "word" is a local/block variable that disappears after the function has been completed, but what is being passed into/assigned to "word."  IN other words, what is being split?

I would have expected there to have been some kind of argument taking an array or hash passed into this function...and then the "each" function run over that..

```
def capitalize_each
  space = " "
  split(space).each{ |word| word.capitalize! }.join(space)     
end   

# Capitalize each word in place.     
def capitalize_each!
  replace capitalize_each end
end
```

Comment: This is not good idiomatic use of Ruby. If you want to turn one array into another array, it's better to use `map` instead of `each`, like this: `words.map{|word|word.capitalize}.join(' ')`. (Without the trailing `!`, `capitalize` makes a new string instead of modifying the old string, and `map` collects those new strings into a new array.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I thought that the method was incomplete because of the absence of `self` at the beginning but it seems that even without it `split` is being called over the string given, `space` would simply be a default separator. This is how the method could look with explicit `self`.

```
class String
    def capitalize_each(separator = ' ')
        self.split(separator).each{|word| word.capitalize!}.join(separator)
    end
end

puts "LOS ANGELES".capitalize_each #=> Los Angeles
puts "LOS_ANGELES".capitalize_each('_') #=> Los_Angeles
```

Comment: `self` is implicit, unless it's ambiguous (i.e. when invoking a writer method).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that before but guessed it when I tried the example and worked as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Let's break this up.

```
split(space)
```

turns the string into a list of would-be words.  (Actually, if the string has two spaces in a row, the list will have an empty string in it.  but that doesn't matter for this purpose.)  I assume this is an instance method in `String`; otherwise, `split` wouldn't be defined.

```
.each { |word| word.capitalize! }
```

`.each` takes each thing in the list (returned by `split`), and runs the following block on it, passing the thing as an arg to the block.  The `|word|` says that this block is going to call the arg "word".  So effectively, what this does is capitalize each word in the string (and each blank string and lonely bit of punctuation too, but again, that's not important -- capitalization doesn't change characters that have no concept of case).

```
.join(space)
```

glues the words back together, reinserting the space that was used to separate them before.  The string it returns is the return value of the function as well.

Answer (score 2):

The string is being split by spaces, i.e. into words.
So the 'each' iterator goes through all the words, one by one, each time the word is in the 'word' object.  So then for that object (word) it uses the capitalize function for it. Finally it all gets joined back together With Spaces. So The End Result is Capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

These methods are meant to be defined in the String class, so what is being split is whatever string you are calling the `capitalize_each` method on.

Some example usage (and a slightly better implementation):

```
class String
  def capitalize_each
    split(/\s+/).each{ |word| word.capitalize! }.join " " 
  end

  def capitalize_each!
    replace capitalize_each
  end
end

puts "hi, i'm a sentence".capitalize_each #=> Hi, I'm A Sentence
```

Comment: Except that `"Hi, i'm a string that     intentionally has a bunch of spaces"` becomes the wrong thing.  If i don't want extra spaces, i'll remove them.  Don't mangle my string for me, kthx.  :)

Comment: Bah.  Can't do the freaking example because Markdown seems to be smooshing spaces together.

Comment: The idea was to handle the case that the string contains tabs or newlines. Perhaps something like `"Hi,\t  i'm  a \tstring".gsub(/\s+\w/) { |s| s.upcase }` would be the ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `|word| word.capitalize!` as a *function* whch you're passing into the `each` method. The function has one argument (`word`) and simply evaluates `.capitalize!` on it.

Now what the `each` method is doing is taking each item in `split(space)` and evaluating your function on it. So:

```
"abcd".each{|x| print x}
```

will evaluate, in order, `print "a"`, `print "b"`, `print "c"`.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000231

To demystify this behavior a bit, it helps to understand exactly what it means to "take each item in __". Basically, any object which is [enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) can be `.each`ed in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to how it gets into your block in the first place, it's yielded into the block.  `#split` returns an Array, and it's `#each` method is doing something along the lines of:

```
for object in stored_objects
  yield object
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but if you want to turn one array into another array, it's idiomatically better to use `map` instead of `each`, like this:

```
words.map{|word|word.capitalize}
```

(Without the trailing `!`, `capitalize` makes a new string instead of modifying the old string, and `map` collects those new strings into a new array. In contrast, `each` returns the old array.)

Or, following gunn's lead:

```
class String
  def capitalize_each
    self.split(/\s/).map{|word|word.capitalize}.join(' ')
  end
end

"foo bar  baz".capitalize_each #=> "Foo Bar  Baz"
```

by default, `split` splits on *strings* of spaces, but by passing a regular expression it matches each *individual* space characters even if they're in a row.